# Проблема с доступом к github через SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

Что можно сделать при  заведении нового репозитория? В

Возникла проблема — добавить ключ в хранилище. В терминалe Git Bash  выполнить команду:

```
ssh-add  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Выполнил это и он мне пишет:

> /c/Users/Евгений/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory

Папку с таким именем не могу сам создать. Как ее можно решить?

Есть только два логических диска  с и d.

Comment: Как генерировали ключ? Согласно описанию [этого](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) справочного руководства?

Answer (score 0):

Это нормально, что этого файла нет. Но его очень легко нагенерировать - читайте официальную документацию https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-windows

Кратко - скорее всего нужна только эта команда

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```